# How to transform from erb file to my config file only in Chef?

Tags: templates, chef-infra, config, erb

I don't want to run chef-client on remote instance but I want to transform my config.erb template file to the config file by interpolating attributes from Chef.

I found this command but normally people use this command for adding attributes to Chef.

```
knife exec -E 'environments.transform("name:my_project") {|n| ..}'
```

So how to run knife command locally but just transform the template erb file?

Comment: Does your .erb template use node attributes or only variables passed to the `template` resource ? You may us `Chef::Template` in your `knife.exec` but this will need to load the target node/roles and environment before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I end up with. I created a script to use ERB lib to translate the template with interpolation:

**tran.rb:**

```
require "erb"

input_file = "/var/lib/j.../config.ini.erb"
output_file = "/var/lib/.../config.ini"

content = File.open(input_file, 'rb').read

template = ERB.new(content)

class ERBContext
    def initialize(env)
        env.transform("name:#{myenv}") do |n|
            attrs = n.default_attributes["nap"]
            attrs.each do |key, value|
                instance_variable_set('@' + key.to_s, value)
            end
        end
    end

    def get_binding
        binding
    end
end

erb_context = ERBContext.new(environments)

config_file = template.result(erb_context.get_binding)
File.open(output_file, 'w+') do |f|
    f.write(config_file)
end
```

Since *knife exec* only expects script files, to set the *myenv* variable, I need to invoke the command like this

```
(echo 'myevn = "xxxxxxxx"' ;  cat ./tran.rb) | sudo knife exec
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange to do it with knife.

My best idea would be to run chef with a 'fake' client_name to render the files locally and then move them. This has been discussed under the name "manage node".

You may have a `managed.rb` config file with an environment variable for the client_name.

Example file in /etc/chef/managed.rb:

```rb
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                ENV['node_name']
client_key               "/path/to/your/targets/keystore/#{ENV['node_name']}.pem"
chef_server_url          'https://chef-server-url.local'
```

Then you may set this environment variable `node_name` to your target node, if you have the validation key it will create the client and node object and work locally.

In a cookbook you may do something like:

```rb
target_dir="/opt/configs/#{node['chef_client']['config']['node_name']}"

directory target_dir do
  action :create
  recursive true
end

execute "copy to #{node['chef_client']['config']['node_name']}" do
  cmd "scp #{target_dir}/* #{node['chef_client']['config']['node_name']}:/etc"
  action :nothing # don't copy at each run if no config file has changed
end

template "#{target_dir}/my_conf" do
  source "my_conf.erb"
  action :create
  notifies :run, "execute[copy to #{node['chef_client']['config']['node_name']}]"
end
```

you can then call chef like this in a crontab:

```sh
59 0 * * * root node_name="my-rp-XX" chef-client -c /etc/chef/managed.rb
```